# What is the imagery of "you shall nurse at the breast of kings"?

Tags: isaiah

ESV Isaiah 60:16

> You shall suck the milk of nations; you shall nurse at the breast of kings; and you shall know that I, the LORD, am your Savior and your Redeemer, the Mighty One of Jacob.

Shouldn't that be "you shall nurse at the breast of queens"?

Comment: Receiving nourishment as one born, is a common image in scripture. It is a genderless concept, sometimes related to the city of Jerusalem. Scripture uses a variety of concepts which, in nature, are gendered, but in the spiritual realm, are not so.

Comment: Hopefully it is a misprint because that's a horrible image!

Comment: @Ruminator "Scripture uses a variety of concepts which, in nature, are gendered, but in the spiritual realm, are not so" Is God a chicken, according to your reading (Ps. 91:4)?

Comment: Men's teats are often covered in unruly hair. God as chicken is not without precedent. https://youtu.be/UKR5epJoeR0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isa 60:16 is quintessential Hebrew idiom for what is described in this chapter and the previous few verses:

> V13-15: The glory of Lebanon will come to you— its cypress, elm, and
> boxwood together— to adorn the place of My sanctuary, and I will
> glorify the place of My feet. The sons of your oppressors will come
> and bow down to you; all who reviled you will fall facedown at your
> feet and call you the City of the LORD, Zion of the Holy One of
> Israel.  Whereas you have been forsaken and despised, with no one
> passing through, I will make you an everlasting pride, a joy from age
> to age.

A similar idiom to the one in Isa 60:16 is presented in Isa 49:23 -

Kings will be your foster fathers, and their queens your nursing mothers. They will bow to you facedown and lick the dust at your feet. Then you will know that I am the LORD; those who hope in Me will never be put to shame.”

Benson, summarizes the thought as follows:

> Isaiah 60:16-17. Thou shalt also suck the milk of the Gentiles — A
> metaphor taken from children drawing nourishment from the breast. The
> sense is, that the church should draw, or receive, the wealth of
> nations, and the riches and power of kings, and whatever is most
> excellent; and that it should come freely and affectionately, as milk
> flows from the breast of the mother. And thou shalt know — Namely,
> shall experience; that I the Lord — Hebrew, Jehovah; am thy Saviour —
> That I have undertaken to save, and that I do and will save thee; the
> mighty One of Jacob — Not only of the literal, but also, and
> especially, of the spiritual Jacob, or Israel: as if he had said,
> These things will certainly be accomplished, for he is the mighty God,
> and so is able; and the God of Jacob, and so is obliged by covenant
> with, and relation to them, to deliver and protect his people.

Answer (score 0):

Kings in this case is a poetic term that parallels nations or kingdoms - "You shall suck the milk of nations; you shall nurse at the breast of kings." Some translators fix the gender problem by describing the breasts in question as "royal" rather than "of kings."

```
You shall suck the milk of the nations,
Suckle at royal breasts. 
And you shall know
That I  GOD am your Savior,
I, The Mighty One of Jacob, am your Redeemer.
```

Normally my preference is to avoid changing the text to make it conform to modern standards of gender neutrality. But here, I think the gender-neutral translation is better. (From the JPS TANAKH: Gender-Sensitive Edition)